# Validate the date format

Tags: vb.net, winforms, date

I have a `textbox` in my form in vb 2010 which should accept only dates and only in the format of `"yyyy/mm/dd"`

How to achieve this? Please help

Comment: Why dont you use datepicker?

Comment: when i use date picker i am getting an error when i try to save the values into a database i get an error based on the format, i tried debugging that and dint work so i thought of using textbox but now i have to limit the textbox to accept only dates please help

Comment: Also its easy to format datepicker to format you like

Comment: Re: error saving to database. If you use SQL parameters to save to the database then you can send a DateTime instead of a String. This will eliminate the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Private Sub TextBox2_Validating(sender As System.Object, e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles TextBox2.Validating
    Dim test As Date
    If Date.TryParseExact(TextBox2.Text.ToString(), "yyyy/mm/dd", _
                          System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, _
                          Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, test) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Ok")
        'TODO: ok
    Else
        e.Cancel = True
        'TODO: not ok
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use datepicker control then you can set to custom format as you like. In the form load event use below

```
DateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom
DateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "yyyy/mm/dd"
```

Let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
DateTime.TryParseExact(dateToTest, "yyyy/MM/dd", New CultureInfo("us-US"), DateTimeStyles.None, result)
```

Comment: That does not answer the question: "should accept only dates and only in the format of "**yyyy/mm/dd**"

Comment: you re right, it's because i m french, so i used french format.